# Сравнить время JS

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, мне нужно сравнить текущее время с временем из определенной колонки и последней строки таблицы. Вот код который сейчас написан:

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

```
var day = new Date();
var curday = day.getDay();
var hours = day.getHours();
var minutes = day.getMinutes();
var curtime = hours+':'+ minutes;
var curtime = curtime.toString();
var rowCount = $('table tr').length;
var rowCount = rowCount - 1;
var rowCount = rowCount.toString();

var row = $('table tr').length - 1;
var row = document.getElementById('table').rows[row].cells[1].innerHTML;
var row_final = row.substring(7,15);


setInterval(function() {

/* ---------------------------------------------- */

if(rowCount === '1' && curtime >= row_final) {
  $('table').css('display', 'none');
  $('#end_one').fadeIn('fast');      
}

if(rowCount === '2' && curtime >= row_final) {
  $('table').css('display', 'none');
  $('#end_one').fadeIn('fast');      
}

if(rowCount === '3' && curtime >= row_final) {
  $('table').css('display', 'none');
  $('#end_one').fadeIn('fast');      
}


if(rowCount === '4' && curtime >= row_final) {
  $('table').css('display', 'none');
  $('#end_one').fadeIn('fast');      
}


if(rowCount === '5' && curtime >= row_final) {
  $('table').css('display', 'none');
  $('#end_one').fadeIn('fast');      
}


if(rowCount === '6' && curtime >= row_final) {
  $('table').css('display', 'none');
  $('#end_one').fadeIn('fast');      
}

if(rowCount === '7' && curtime >= row_final) {
  $('table').css('display', 'none');
  $('#end_one').fadeIn('fast');      
}

});
/* ---------------------------------------------- */
```

Код работает но криво.. он считает что 11:40 > 12:50 как исправить данную проблему. Заранее извиняюсь за свой не очень грамотный вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если честно ваш код не так понятен... поэтому приведу пример как можно проверить две даты, а дальше вы сами :)

```
var start_time  = '2018-02-10';
var end_time    = '2018-02-15';

if(new Date(start_time) <= new Date(end_time))
{
.....
}
```

Comment: спасибо, сейчас проверю )